# SQLite foreign key constraints

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, sqlitejdbc

I am using Java with [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/).

I was struggling to understand why my foreign keys were not acting as constraints, until I read the following:

*Prior to version 3.6.19, SQLite did not support foreign key constraints.*

I then took a closer look at the SQLiteJDBC website and found:

*The current version is v056, based on SQLite 3.6.14.2.*

There is a solution documented [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ForeignKeyTriggers), although it is a very old article - is it still  the best way to proceed?  Would other SQLite Java connectors be recommended?

Comment: Is this a situation in which upgrading is an expensive operation? Upgrading is the best way, given the newer version provides exactly the functionality you want.

Comment: I am very open to alternatives; it's all a learning curve, be it a frustrating one.  How do you mean newer version?  Edit: I think there's been some confusion - the SQLiteJDBC was built off a version off SQLite prior to foreign key constraints being implemented.

Comment: My mistake. It turns out there _isn't_ a newer version of SQLiteJDBC based on anything above 3.6.19. In fact, it hasn't been updated since 2009. So, that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite support in Java seems to [not be so great](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers).

You may be able to rebuild [javasqlite](http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/) against a newer version of SQLite, since it depends on:

> SQLite 2.4.12 **or higher**

Whether it will actually work remains to be seen, but I think SQLite has a fairly stable API.

You could also try to build SQLiteJDBC [from source](https://github.com/crawshaw/sqlitejdbc) against a newer version of SQLite.

EDIT:

Actually, [Xerial SQLiteJDBC](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) has been [updated much more recently](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC#News). Apparently it's a lot slower though since it's pure Java.